# React SCSS modules not working due to imports in the .scss files

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I am trying to set up SCSS modules on a React app, in Typescript. The header of one of my .scss files looks like this:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/";
```

due to the fact that I need variables, functions etc. However, webpack isn't really happy that I'm trying to do this.

```
error  in ./src/main/webapp/app/modules/profile/components/profile-menu/profile-menu.module.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
      Expected "{".
  stdin 2:249  root stylesheet
      in /home/adrianpop/CRESCDI/projects/jhipster/gateway/src/main/webapp/app/modules/profile/components/profile-menu/profile-menu.module.scss (line 2, column 249)

 [....]
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.tsx
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js react-hot-loader/patch ./src/main/webapp/app/index
```

Notice that a simple `import './profile-menu.scss';` is working great, but imported as `import css from './profile-menu.module.scss';` (separate file with the same SCSS code) doesn't work anymore. I find it very hard to set up SCSS Modules in React (Typescript). In the same time, the project wasn't generated using `create-react-app`, but JHipster, so most of the tutorials online doesn't work or have a totally different structure than mine.

Right now, `webpack.dev.js` looks like this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            implementation: sass
          }
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I also needed to add the following piece of code in `typings.d.ts` for Typescript to recognize .scss files as modules.

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[className: string]: string};
  export = content;
}
```

Where is my mistake and how can I properly configure webpack to support (S)CSS modules in React? I feel that I'm close but there are some small mistakes being made.